# Dir command returning unwanted results in Windows 10

Tags: windows, command-line

I'd like to list all reparse points (i.e.: file and directory symlinks and Junction Points) in a folder with this command in Windows 10 Command Prompt

DIR /S /A:L c:\Users\anton\onedrive

Yet, I get all files in this folder (these are offline files).
Shouldn't I get only reparse points?

Windows 10 21H1
[image]

Comment: Perhaps you can find an answer here - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-reparsepoint

Comment: This is normal because OneDrive marks the "offline only" files as reparse points. [OneDrive "Files On Demand" status](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/375f3933-fcab-450c-bb9c-da54155549e2/how-do-i-getset-onedrive-quotfiles-on-demandquot-status-from-powershell?forum=ITCG)

Comment: Thanks a lot for claryfying  w32sh